# Y-combinator implementation in javascript and elixir

Tags: javascript, elixir, y-combinator

I've been studying the Y Combinator, and I get how it works on paper, but I don't know yet understand how it can be implemented in a programming language.

According to this page: http://matt.might.net/articles/implementation-of-recursive-fixed-point-y-combinator-in-javascript-for-memoization/

The derivation of Y combinator goes:

```
Y(F) = F(Y(F))
# Of course, if we tried to use it, it would never work because the function Y immediately calls itself, leading to infinite recursion.
# Using a little λ-calculus, however, we can wrap the call to Y in a λ-term: 
Y(F) = F(λ x.(Y(F))(x))
#  Using another construct called the U combinator, we can eliminate the recursive call inside the Y combinator, which, with a couple more transformations gets us to: 
Y = (λh.λF.F(λ x.((h(h))(F))(x))) (λh.λF.F(λ x.((h(h))(F))(x)))
```

How can he expand `Y(F)` to be `λ x.(Y(F))(x)`? And how can he use the U Combinator?

Here is the implementation in Javascript and Elixir:

```
# javascript
var Y = function (F) {
    return (function (x) {
        return F(function (y) { return (x(x))(y);});
    })(function (x) {
        return F(function (y) { return (x(x))(y);});
    });
};

# elixir
defmodule Combinator do
    def fix(f) do
        (fn x -> 
            f.(fn y -> (x.(x)).(y) end) 
        end).(fn x -> 
            f.(fn y -> (x.(x)).(y) end) 
        end)
    end
end
```

If this is the formula: `Y = \f.(\x.f(x x))(\x.f(x x))`, what is the relationship between f, x in the lambda expression, and the f, x, y in the implementation above? The x looks like it's the same x, the f looks like the same f. Then what is `y`? Specifically why is the lambda equivalent of `x x` being wrapped in a function that uses `y`?

Is `y` kind of like the arguments to the function!?

Comment: You should watch this Video on functional-ish programming in Ruby by Jim Weirich. During the talk, he derives the Y Combinator step by step. Very impressive, educational and fun to watch! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FITJMJjASUs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is y kind of like the arguments to the function!?

Yes, exactly. Lambda calculus is implicitly [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Instead of `x x` you might as well write `\y.x x y`.

Comment: Are there cases where the function being "Y-combinated" doesn't have any arguments, and therefore not requiring us to wrap the `x x`? Or does all functions that are being "Y-combinated" have parameters, since they are reentrant recursive functions. Also what might you call the "x" if you were to give an semantic label?

Comment: More importantly if there will always be a curried argument, why does the lambda calculus expression not represent it in `Y = \f.(\x.f(x x))(\x.f(x x))`? Wouldn't it make it clearer if there was something that stated that `x x` needed arguments?

Comment: No, the Y combinator is explictly defined as the fix-point of one-parameter functions (and everything else wouldn't make much sense). I don't know whether there's a name for the `x` function.

Comment: Would lambda calculus be more clear if… - yes, maybe. But clarity is not necessarily the aim of this notation :-) In fact, [omitting parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) is often more clear - and you don't "need" them when it's "obvious" from the type